# Jupyter notebook show error: Exception while loading config file

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I open Anaconda and then open Jupyter notebook (6.1.4).

http://localhost:8903/tree is opened

However, when I click New Python3 a blank page with below address opened. It keep spinning, look like trying to open the python3

http://localhost:8959/notebooks/Untitled21.ipynb?kernel_name=python3

Also a notice box "Application Launch error" appear with following text

Can anyone help, please?
Thanks
HHC

```
[E 10:40:06.955 NotebookApp] Exception while loading config file C:\Users\HPNEW\.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\HPNEW\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 737, in _load_config_files
config = loader.load_config()
File "C:\Users\HPNEW\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\loader.py", line 616, in load_config
self._read_file_as_dict()
File "C:\Users\HPNEW\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\loader.py", line 648, in _read_file_as_dict
exec(compile(f.read(), conf_filename, 'exec'), namespace, namespace)
File "C:\Users\HPNEW\.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.py", line 149
c.NotebookApp.browser = u'C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe %s'
^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
[I 10:40:07.629 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 10:40:07.630 NotebookApp] The port 8889 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 10:40:07.630 NotebookApp] The port 8890 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 10:40:07.631 NotebookApp] The port 8891 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 10:40:07.631 NotebookApp] The port 8892 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 10:40:07.890 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Users\HPNEW\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 10:40:07.891 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\HPNEW\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 10:40:07.898 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\HPNEW
[I 10:40:07.898 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.1.4 is running at:
[I 10:40:07.898 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8959/?token=042d81d0eafc2db7d720a15adc7a5815bec1dedf42d6b248
[I 10:40:07.899 NotebookApp] or http://127.0.0.1:8959/?token=042d81d0eafc2db7d720a15adc7a5815bec1dedf42d6b248
[I 10:40:07.899 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 10:40:07.969 NotebookApp] 

To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
file:///C:/Users/HPNEW/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-13804-open.html
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
http://localhost:8959/?token=042d81d0eafc2db7d720a15adc7a5815bec1dedf42d6b248
or http://127.0.0.1:8959/?token=042d81d0eafc2db7d720a15adc7a5815bec1dedf42d6b248
```

Comment: I would suggest you to reinstall jupyter notebook. First uninstall jupyter using `pip uninstall jupyter` and then reinstall using `pip install jupyter`. Hope this solves the issue.

Comment: uninstall and reinstall jupyter still not working for me.